# Asus router won't connect to the internet: ISP DHCP is not functioning properly

Tags: router, dhcp, isp

I am trying to connect a new router to my modem, however the router is telling me that it cannot connect to the internet:

> "Your ISP DHCP is not functioning properly".

I've tried factory resetting, and messing around with the settings, and nothing is working.

Comment: Connect a computer directly to the modem and make sure it has internet. You should start by connecting the WAN port on the router to a LAN port on the modem. Make sure you are not using a DMZ port if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is unplugging the modem for at least 10min. It seems that it has something to do with MAC address binding. Disconnecting from the ISP for 10+ min seems to reset something.

---

**Edit**: As a first step [follow @John's comment](https://superuser.com/questions/1519391/asus-router-wont-connect-to-the-internet-dhcp-is-not-functioning-properly#comment2300535_1519391) about connecting your computer directly to the WAN port on the modem to make sure that there is an internet connection. If there is, and nothing else is working, follow the instructions above.

Comment: This worked for me as well, and I agree it's probably an issue with the provider being confused as to whether or not the address of your modem is entitled to a DHCP address. Leaving the cable modem unplugged for ~15 minutes (I went and took a shower) resolved the issue.